# Testing React Native App on TestFlight

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, testflight

I have been trying to find documentation on how to properly create a React Native build that does not need to be on a local network and can use carrier network, and can then be deployed for testing onto TestFlight.

I have been able to get stables on TestFlight but can't figure out how to get the App to run outside the local network.

I have tried this with no luck:

> Inside the project AppDelegate.m, uncomment the line below the OPTION 2 comment:
>
> ```
> jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
> ```
>
> This causes the app to load from pre-bundled file on disk. Next, with the development server running (started with npm start), you can curl the URL in the comment, adding an extra dev query parameter:
>
> curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle\?dev\=0 -o main.jsbundle'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Since [v0.14](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/0.14.0) JS and images are automatically packaged into the iOS app using `Bundle React Native code and images` Xcode build phase.

All you have to do is run the app from XCode and:

> 1. Open `ios/YourApp/AppDelegate.m`
> 2. Uncomment the line, `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] ...`

Answer (score 0):

@rahul2001 I think the answer you're looking for is here...
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#using-offline-bundle

I've not used TestFlight, but I've found Fabric.io (by twitter) to be super easy to use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but that is not working. I tried that already and get this:

$ react-native bundle
-bash: react-native: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to be listening to an externally available IP (like something on AWS) instead of a local network specific IP.

You'd use the prebundled binary instead of loading the app from the development server. Your own backend would live at the IP mentioned above.